# How to generate a model that extends another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I want to generate the following model in my rails app.

```
class MovieExtension < MyApp::MovieModel
  self.bar= :count
  dimension :title
end
```

Now my App is another gem that I have installed locally that consists of the MovieModel. How to generate the following model and migration for the same . Any Ideas?

Comment: Depends on what gem we are talking about here. Don't be so vague. Some gems have a generator to create the migration for you and in some cases you'll have to do it yourself. Also you're using the term "extends" which is used for parallel inheritance with modules yet the example is classical inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try it by requiring the file you needed
`require 'my_app/movie_model'`

or if its a module you can include it and you can use those methods defined in it

```
 class MovieExtension < ActiveRecord
   include MyApp::MovieModel
   self.bar= :count
   dimension :title
 end
```

Comment: How do I generate a migration for this.

Comment: You do not need a migration to write include or require.

Comment: You need a migration only to create the model. Once the model is created you can write include or require depending on your requirement